# Add arrays to values in hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
h={'key1'=>'value1', 'key2'=>'value2', 'key3'=>'value3'}
```

and for each key, a corresponding array:

```
array1=['string1', 'string2'] 
array2=['string3', 'string4']
array3=['string5', 'string6']
```

I'd like to get a hash like this:

```
h={ 'key1'=>['value1', ['string1', 'string2']],
    'key2'=>['value2', ['string3', 'string4']],
    'key3'=>['value3', ['string5', 'string6']] }
```

Comment: Could you please put your code here and ask for the exact problem?

Comment: I'd just like to clarify. Basically, what you want to do is to add the contents of the array to the values assigned to the key such as that : i.e. `'key1' => ['value1',array1]` or `'key1' => { 'value1' => 'array1' }`? It would help us help you better :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you've tried. It's easier, and better, for us to correct your code, than for us to write something from scratch and you retrofit it into your old code. Also, it's expected that you'll show us your attempt so we know you're not just fishing for someone to write the code for you. Also, your `h` is not a hash, it's actually an array consisting of a single hash containing the key/value pairs of `key1` ... `key10`.

Comment: Sorry. originally i wanted `h={'key1'=>'value1', [string1...string2]...'key10'=>'value10',[string1...string2] }` but...if you advise me how to realize `h={'key1'=>[value1',array1]...'key10'=>['value10',array10] }` I will be grateful to you

Comment: I trust my edit is consistent with your intent. Note that I changed the hash and arrays to remove `...` so that it is a complete example that can be referenced in answers.

Comment: I appreciate the greenie, but in future consider waiting longer before making a selection, so as to not discourage other answers. Feel free to remove the checkmark. You may find other answers interesting, as there are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
h = { 'key1'=>'value1', 'key2'=>'value2', 'key3'=>'value3' }
array1 = ["my dog", "has", "fleas"] 
array2 = ["my cat", "has", "9 lives"]
array3 = ["my pig", "--wait, I don't", "have a pig"]
array  = [array1, array2, array3]
```

There are many ways to do this. Here are two. Note that all assume that key-insertion order in `h` is preserved, which is only the case if you are using Ruby v1.9+. Moreover, the type of object (here an array) you are adding to each value of the hash `h` is irrelevant. The same solution would apply if the objects to be added (the elements of `array`) were any types of object (hashes, strings, symbols, class instances, whatever).

**#1: Use [Enumerable#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip)**

```
h.zip(array).each { |(k,v),a| h[k] = [v,a] }
h
  #=> {"key1"=>["value1", ["my dog", "has", "fleas"]],
  #    "key2"=>["value2", ["my cat", "has", "9 lives"]],
  #    "key3"=>["value3", ["my pig", "--wait, I don't", "have a pig"]]}
```

**#2: Use [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge)**

This method uses the form of `Hash#merge` that employs a hash to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. Since `h` is being merged with itself, the block is invoked for every key. If you wish to modify `h` in place, use [Hash#merge!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) (aka `update`) instead.

```
a = array.dup
h.merge(h) { |_,v| [v, a.shift] }
  #=> {"key1"=>["value1", ["my dog", "has", "fleas"]],
  #    "key2"=>["value2", ["my cat", "has", "9 lives"]],
  #    "key3"=>["value3", ["my pig", "--wait, I don't", "have a pig"]]}
```

Comment: Cary, is that legal structure?: `h={'nik'=>'ruby',[a,b,c,d], 'mik'=>'python',[f,r,t,y]}`

Comment: Dmytro, no it is not, as each element of `h` (separated by commas) must be a key-value pair ( key=>value). ['a','b','c','d'] and ['f','r','t','y'] do not meet that requirement. h={'nik'=>['ruby',['a','b','c','d']],... is ok, however. Note that in `[a,b]`, `a` and `b` must be variables or methods in order that the array be a valid object. That's why I changed them earlier in this comment to literals (strings, but I could have used symbols: `[:a, :b,..`.

Comment: Thank you Cary. originally i  I had two arrays `array1=[string1...string10]` and `array2=[string1...string10]` i'm create hash (i think): `h=Hash[array1.zip array2]` but later appeared data as a arrays which i can use as value for current key1...key10.

Comment: Cary, I'm sorry. If i have `h = { 'key1'=>'value1' }` and `array1 = ["my dog", "has", "fleas"]` for getting `h = { 'key1'=>['value1',["my dog", "has", "fleas"] ]}` i must use .merge?

Comment: Dmytro, you could just write `h['key1'] = [h['key1'] , array1]`.

Comment: But if 'key1' can take a different value? i.e. `h = { 'cat'=>'value1' }` or `h = { 'dog'=>'value1' }`

Comment: maybe: `h[h.keys.first] = [h.keys.first['a'], a]` ?